# "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when insert to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV file with 19 columns. I write a python program to read this CSV and insert it to PostgreSQL DB.
The CSV format is:

[image]

my code is :

```
import csv
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=dataset user=postgres password=@****")
cur = conn.cursor()

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(
            "INSERT into dig_cycle_data VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", row)

conn.commit()
```

I received this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: How many columns have your CSV rows? Can you check? It seems to me like you have more columns than `%s` in your request

Comment: Things to look for 1) Do you have more then 19 columns in `dig_cycle_data`, maybe an autoincrement one? If so you will need to specify columns as `dig_cycle_data(col1, col2 ...)`. 2) Verify what each `row` contains. There could be some characters(e.g. line endings) in a field that is causing it to be split into two fields.

Comment: @romainsalles As you can the number of columns and %s are 19.

Comment: @adrianKlaver Yes, as you can see there are 19 columns. how can find a row? I received this `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adminuser\Downloads\dig\inserttopsg.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur.execute(
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting `

Comment: In your code above the `cur.execute(... )` add print(row). That will show you the contents of the row that caused the error.  Also can you add as update to your question the schema for `dig_cycle_data` as returned by  `\d dig_cycle_data` in `psql'.